# Screening list of stocks by a specific function

Tags: r, quantmod

I have this sample list of stocks:

```
stock.list = c("AMZN","GOOGL","AAPL","FB","TSLA")
```

And I have this following function:

```
fnct<-function(x){
require(quantmod)
ticker <- getSymbols(x,src="google", auto.assign=FALSE)
#number of rows
n<-nrow(ticker)

# last day's close
lastvalue <- as.numeric((ticker[n,4]))

# previous day's close
prevvalue <- as.numeric((ticker[n-1,4]))

# price change
prchange <- lastvalue - prevvalue

res<-(

paste0(prchange)

)
return(res)
}
```

The output of the function is a number that represents a difference between the closure prices of the last day and the day before that (essentially, positive number in the output means that the stock price went up, and negative means that it went down)

For example, using this function for `AMZN` today returns a positive number:

```
 > fnct('AMZN')
[1] "17.3200000000001"
```

I would like to apply the function to the list of stocks so that it only displays those stocks names that had positive changes (`>0`), and, if possible, numeric value of change next to them (essentially, eliminating stocks with negative change)

So the ideal output would be something like this:

```
AMZN    17.3200000000001
GOOGL   14.95
...and so on
```

This is what I came up with so far, but it does not work

```
for(x in stock.list) {
paste0(x,fnct(x))
}
```

I know this does not eliminate stocks with negative changes, but this is how far I could go. Even this doesn't seem to work.

Ideally, it should be robust enough to skip `NA`'s (for example, misspelled stock name in the list, or missing data for a particular stock in the list)

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smallest fix would be to change your loop to...

```
for (x in stock.list) {
    if(as.numeric(fnct(x)) >= 0) print(paste(x, fnct(x)))
}
```

It's your function that needs to made tolerant to typos and the simplest behaviour is to have it skip over any unfound symbols instead of trying to guess what you were going for.

```
fnct <- function(x) {
    require(quantmod)

    ticker <- suppressWarnings(tryCatch({ getSymbols(x, src="google", auto.assign=FALSE) }, error = function(e) NULL))

    if (!is.null(ticker)) {

        #number of rows
        n <- nrow(ticker)

        # last day's close
        lastvalue <- as.numeric((ticker[n,4]))

        # previous day's close
        prevvalue <- as.numeric((ticker[n-1,4]))

        # price change
        prchange <- lastvalue - prevvalue

        res <- paste0(prchange)
    } else {
        res <- "Not found"
    }

    return(res)
}
```

Then your loop becomes:

```
for (x in stock.list) {
    result <- fnct(x)
    if (result == "Not found" || (as.numeric(result) >= 0 & as.numeric(result) < 100) ) print(paste(x, result))
}
```

Just to clarify, this is the most direct way to go from what you had to what you want. It's not necessarily the best way.

Comment: this is exactly what I was asking, but how can it be made tolerant to typos? for example, it crashes if I enter a typo error in Google ticker name `stock.list = c("AMZN","GOOGGL","AAPL","FB","TSLA")
`

Comment: @Oposum Updated answer to cope with bad stock names.

Comment: thank you, that exactly answers what I asked. Now, this is somewhat outside of the initial question, but how would I indicate two conditions to be met instead of one, `as.numeric(result) >= 0` but at the same time `as.numeric(result) <100`?

Comment: @Oposum see above

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

Within a for loop, you need to use the print function to see the result of a paste statement.

Secondly, there's no reason to convert the price change with "paste", you should keep it as a numeric value.  Try this:

```
require(quantmod)

stock.list = c("AMZN","GOOGL","AAPL","FB","TSLA")

fnct<-function(x){
    ticker <- getSymbols(x,src="google", auto.assign=FALSE)
    n<-nrow(ticker)
    lastvalue <- as.numeric((ticker[n,4]))
    prevvalue <- as.numeric((ticker[n-1,4]))
    prchange <- lastvalue - prevvalue
    return(prchange)
}

prchanges <- sapply(stock.list, fnct)
results <- data.frame(symbol=stock.list, prchange=prchanges, stringsAsFactors=F)

results_positive <- subset(results, prchange > 0)
print(results_positive)

> print(results_positive)
      symbol prchange
AMZN    AMZN    17.32
GOOGL  GOOGL    14.95
AAPL    AAPL     0.78
FB        FB     2.03
```

Comment: looks great. But, it crashes if I enter a typo error in Google ticker name `stock.list = c("AMZN","GOOGGL","AAPL","FB","TSLA")` , how can it be bypassed?
`

Answer (score 1):

Here's how do that with lists and `lapply`:

```
stock.list = list("AMZN","GOOGL","AAPL","FB","TSLA") #put tickers in a list
res <- lapply(stock.list,fnct) #use func on list
res <- lapply(res,as.numeric)  #change to numeric
res <- Map(cbind,stock.list,res) #add ticker
res <- do.call(rbind,res)       #unlist to table
res <- as.data.frame(res)
colnames(res) <- c("Stock","Change")
res[res$Change!=0,]  #show only stocks with non-zero changes

  Stock            Change
1  AMZN  17.3200000000001
2 GOOGL             14.95
3  AAPL 0.780000000000001
4    FB              2.03
5  TSLA             -2.56
```

Answer (score 1):

A very compact ( no custom function, no loop ) and straightforward way to get the last price changes would be by using the `qmao` package, which already has a function to give you the price frame (`PF`) of a group of symbols.

```
library(quantmod)
library(qmao)

stock.list = c("AMZN","GOOGL","AAPL","FB","TSLA")
getSymbols(stock.list,src="google")
prices <- PF(stock.list,silent = TRUE)
priceChange <- diff(prices)
t(last(priceChange))
      2017-04-18
AMZN        1.79
GOOGL      -1.14
AAPL       -0.63
FB         -0.46
TSLA       -1.19
```